# hacker earth shows input mismatch and NZEC error

Tags: java

Here is a simple question where you have to take an int and an string as an input and return the int input multiplied by 2 and string input as it is.
Im giving the inputs correctly even then it is giving the same errors

```
   import java.util.*;
         class TestClass {
                    public static void main(String args[] )  {

                     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                     int x = scan.nextInt();
                     String y = scan.nextLine();
                      x = x * 2;
                      System.out.println(x);
                       System.out.println(y);
                                                           }
                         }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score -1):

```java
package codechef;

import java.util.*;

class HackerearthProblem {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        String y = scan.next();
        x = x * 2;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use scan.next() Instead of scan.nextLine();